# Place div inside div in a responsive design

Tags: html, css

I want to place a div (profile picture) inside anoter div (profile banner) in a responsive design. Not realy a problem but I also want the inside div (profile picture) slightly on the outside of the outer div. It just have to display like this on pc and it can display differently on mobile and tablet.

Heres a picture of what im trying to create:
[image]

So what I want is a responsive div inside a div with the inner div slightly on the outside. It has to be responsive because of different screen resolutions.

I know this is more of a request then a answer, but I have no clue how to do this

Comment: You can use Absolute Positioning for the profile picture.

Comment: just use absolute then position the profile picture

Comment: Ok so what error do you get ? What have you tried ?

Comment: @Weedoze here, I have created a fiddle https://fiddle.jshell.net/4mLcpe03/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Codepen demo:**

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dpgXqp

```css
* {
  transition: .5s all ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: .5s all ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s all ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: .5s all ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .5s all ease-in-out;
}
.propic {
  border: 2px solid #e2e2e2;
  margin-top: -130px;
  margin-left: 70px;
}
.cover {
  border: 2px solid #e2e2e2;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.propic:hover,
.cover:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 10px #9f9f9f;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 10px #9f9f9f;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 10px #9f9f9f;
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 10px #9f9f9f;
  -o-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 10px #9f9f9f;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-2UPJD5hegLs/UR4MlzkGTUI/AAAAAAAAAWk/xpff536gpIQ/s1600/mycover.jpg" alt="Cover_Photo" class="cover" />
<br />
<img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-b3Ty2n3mrOc/UR4MAXUXHDI/AAAAAAAAAWQ/CS31CdrnNY8/s1600/profp.jpg" class="propic" alt="Profile_picture" />
```

Codepen link:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dpgXqp

Answer (score 2):

you have to use `position:absolute;` for the inner div and `position:relative;` for the outside div. also if you want the text to be placed after the profile picture inside the parent box, you must give the parent box a padding left. **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/v6moqbst/)**

```css
.user-info{
  background:#444;
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding:16px 16px 16px 216px;
  color:#FFF;
  font-size:32px;
  }
  .profile-picture{
    background:#444;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    position:absolute;
    border:2px solid #FFF;
    left:50px;
    bottom:-50px;
    color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;
  }
```

```html
<div class="user-info">
  <div class="profile-picture">Profile Picture</div>
  
  User Information
</div>
```

also if you wanna handle the responsive, you can use media queries (resize to see the it): **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/v6moqbst/1/)**

Answer (score -1):

```css
.parent{
    width: 400px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:red;
}
.sibling{
position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 150px;
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   
</div>
 <div class="sibling">
    </div>
```

Comment: i just gave him sample.